# Power Apps, Submit form + Send email in one button

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

How do I Submit form + Send an email in one button? It doesn't seem to work to submit + send email.

```
SubmitForm(EditForm1);

Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(DataCardValue12.Selected.Email,"Tracker " & DataCardValue9.Text,

"<font-size=14>

Hello,<br>
<br>

A request to review  Documentation has been submitted and <b><u>requires your action</u></b>. 
<br>
<a href='link'> Tracker </a>");
```

Comment: are you getting any error while using above formula?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a PowerAutomate flow upon form submission that sends the email.